# How to consume multiple message on rabbitMq consumer

Tags: java, rabbitmq

How to consume bulk (something like prefetchCount = 10) messages in one shot in spring framework of rabbitMq?

**Note - I am implementing Consumer not Listener**

As of now I'm using

```
Message message = amqpTemplate.receive("Queue_Name");
```

But the problem with the above solution is, it fetches only one message in one shot

Answer (score -1):

I'm curious why you want to process 10 at a time.  Typically messages are discreet and processed individually.  That's why RabbitMQ will only pass a single message to a given instance of a consumer at a time.  A  PrefetchCount of 10 will call the consumer 10 times, with one message each.  If you have to process 10 messages at once for some reason, you would need to receive messages individually, acknowledge each one and store them in a collection as they're received.  Then when your count = 10, start processing them.

Comment: This should be a comment on the question and not an answer.

Comment: The explanation of how prefetch behaves is an answer.  I apologize if the initial question should have been a separate comment.